# Unable to place order on checkout page for configurable products magento 2.1.8

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product

I am unable to place order on checkout page for configurable products in **Magento 2.1.8**.
It's working perfect for simple products.
At the same time i noticed that the quantity of configurable product is showing as zero even I change it.
Please help me to fix it.

Comment: The community here will need much more information to help you. Are you able to add the configurable to your cart? But then does the checkout fail? Is Magento showing any error messages on the front end? Do you have any error messages in your server log, php log or the Magneto logs under [app root]/vat/log ? The quantity of 0 is normally okay because it is the stock level of the underlying simple product that is used for stock control.

Comment: Yes am able to add the configurable to cart .stock count is reducing per order also,But when am selecting the payment method and placing the order page keeps on loading with no changes.Number of log files are generated regarding payment.